# Comment as part of environment

Tags: environments, comments

I am looking for a method to create such an environment:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{environmentName}{Visible text for program}

Invisible text for program

\end{environmentName}
\end{document}
```

Invisible text has to be "inside" environment (can't be argument in {}).

I tried to use *comment* environment inside my *environmentName* definition, but it didn't work.

Comment: If I understand what you mean you want an environment that will make TeX process `Visible text for program` and ignore `Invisible text for program`, is that it?

Comment: In PDF file you will just see text: "Visible text for program".
"Invisible text for program" will be treated as normal % comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an overkill but you can use `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myenv}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{This will be printed.}
This will not be printed,
even if you write wrong stuff like \misspelledorundefinedmacro.
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Depending on how the environment is used this might need some adjustments for correct spacing.

Comment: @HiddenHanitatis did you even chaech what campas example does? This does exaxtly what you are asking for, everything inside the env is ignored, including the macros that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) package.

Any text between `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` will be discarded.

Otherwise you can put your "invisible" text inside an `\iffalse ... \fi`, so that TeX will skip anything inside it.

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

Visible text for program

\begin{comment}

Invisible text for program

\end{comment}

Another visible text for program

\iffalse

Another invisible text for program

\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know how to use comments. It's just one-time solution.

Comment: @HiddenHanitatis Oh, sorry for wasting time trying to help you.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: A rule of thumb: Don't try to answer unclear questions -- you won't get much 'reward'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good point... Thanks for the advice `:)`